# Geting all the options in dropdown list and camparing it with single option using selenium webdriver and java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

can any one tell me how to get all the options present in a dropdown list and compare it with a single option using selenium web driver..

I tried out with this code

```
Select dropdown = new Select(_driver.findElement(EventListOptionList));
        List<WebElement> Options = dropdown.getOptions();
        for (WebElement el : Options) {
          if(el.getText.equals("event1")){
             System.out.printLn("Option is present")
          }
        }
```

But it is showing error in this line

```
List<WebElement> Options = dropdown.getOptions();
```

And the error is "Remove type arguments"

Comment: Can u provide the HTML snippet?

Comment: Is it a compile time error at that specific line or run time error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have imported this List class: "java.awt.List". Hence the error.
**Please remove that and import "java.util.List"** instead. This will certainly resolve your problem.

Comment: Awesome.. :) If this has helped you, please mark it as answer. Thanks. :)